# Грузино или грузинско?

Tags: выбор-слов

Грузино или грузинско? Какое правило?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, единого правила нет, всё упирается в традиции. Даже орфографический словарь [даёт два варианта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAGyw.png) написания "грузин(ск)о-российский" и других подобных прилагательных.